# Books about scalability and high availability of internet applications

Tags: scalability, load-balancing, high-availability

I am looking for some good books about the following topics: scalability, high availability and load balancing of internet applications. Could you recommend any?

Comment: [Theo Schlossnagle - "Scalable Internet Architectures"](http://www.amazon.com/Scalable-Internet-Architectures-Theo-Schlossnagle/dp/067232699X)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thinks that these ones are useful:

- [Cal Henderson - "Building Scalable Web Sites"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Building-Scalable-Web-Sites-Henderson/dp/0596102356)
- [Theo Schlossnagle - "Scalable Internet Architectures"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232699X)
- [George Reese - "Cloud Application Architectures"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596156367)
- [Bill Wilder - "Cloud Architecture Patterns"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023777.do)

Thanks for you anwser!